# Trying to make it work Regex/url/views on Django

Tags: python, regex, django, url, pycharm

I'm new with Python and Django and I'm  trying to make a url regex using PyCharm, but I have no clue why it doesn't work.

I have this example...

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import (home, client_detail,)

urlpatterns = [
   path(r'^$', home),
   path(r'^/cliente/(?P<id>\d+)/$', client_detail),
   path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And I have a *views.py* that has the below code inside it:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('HOME')

def client_detail(request, id):
    return HttpResponse(id)
```

The question is: When I write `path(r'^/cliente/(?P<id>\d+)/$', client_detail)` instead `path(r'/cliente/<id>', client_detail)`, I receive the print error below

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? Thanks in advance! :)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLYhr.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `path` but your pattern is a regex. Use then `re_path`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re-path

```
re_path(r'^/cliente/(?P<id>\d+)/$', client_detail),
```